# Thymeleaf dynamically create forms using th:each

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to know how to create forms that uses `th:object` for each object looped in a `th:each`. For example, I have the following code.

**HTML**

```
<th:block th:each="store: ${stores}">
    <form th:object="${store}" th:action="@{/modify-store}">
        <input th:field="*{idStorePk}"/>
        <input th:field="*{name}"/>
        <input th:field="*{phoneNumber}"/>
        <button type="submit">Modify</button>
    </form>
</th:block>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stores")
public String getIndex(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("stores", storeService.getAllStores());
    return "store";
}
```

So, I would like to add a form for each object, but it seems that it is not possible and I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'store' available as request attribute
```

So, I decided to add a `@ModelAttribute` in my controller, but can't get to return the actual store.

```
@ModelAttribute("store")
public Store getStore(Store store) {
    return store;
}
```

With this approach all my forms have null values. I also tried to add a `@PathVariable`, but can't see to bind it using `th:object`. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You are not sending plain(empty) store object to `store`. alongwith list of `stores ` send `store `also.

Comment: I don't want a plain empty store, but for each store I want every one if it's values. Also, I have tried several ways, including sending an empty store, but I still can't get each store's values using `th:object`.

Comment: Your issue is obvious . The model does not set properly . Still wonder why you are iterating forms .

Comment: I want to create a modify form for each store, dynamically. That is why I am iterating each store and creating a new store. The problem is obvious, the solution is not. It doesn't seem to be possible using `th:object`, so that is why I asked.

Comment: I am also stuck at a smilar thing: i am trying to create multiple forms on a page using th:each , b ut getting 'Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'XYS' available as request attribute'. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @PankajVatsa in a way yes, but it could be seem as a work around. I will post it as answer.

Comment: @AlainCruz Please do post the answer..

Comment: @PankajVatsa just did. Hope it helps. Remember to use the exact name of your model's attribute names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So for anyone stuck at a similar problem. I find out a work around that might help you out. First, you can't use `th:object`, it simply won't cut it. Instead, do the following.

```
<th:block th:each="store: ${stores}">
    <form class="store-form" th:action="@{/modify-store}">
        <input th:name="idStorePk" th:value="${store.idStorePk}"/>
        <input th:name="name" th:value="${store.name}"/>
        <input th:name="phoneNumber" th:value="${store.phoneNumber}"/>
        <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Modify</button>
    </form>
</th:block>
```

Then just add something similar to the controller.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/modify-store")
@ResponseBody
public boolean deleteEntry(@ModelAttribute Store store) throws Exception {
    // Your code here...
    return true;
}
```

If you want to send it asynchronously then you will need to add some `JS` code in order for it to work. It should look something like the code below.

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.store-form');
forms.forEach(form => {
   form.addEventListener('submit', event => {

   // Stop the normal form submit triggered by the submit button
   event.preventDefault();

   const formInputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
   let formData = new FormData();
   for (let input of formInputs) {
       formData.append(input.name, input.value);
   }

   fetch(form.action,
   {
        method: form.method,
        body: formData
   })
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
   .finally(() => console.log("Done"));
});
```

Comment: This answer helped unblock me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending **stores** in your controller in model-attribute and on your second controller where you're submitting your form you're using **store** that's the reason you're getting this error. So correct the spelling error on any one of your controller. Like this :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stores")
public String getIndex(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("stores", storeService.getAllStores());
    return "store";
}
```

And Your second controller where you're submitting your form will be like this -

```
@ModelAttribute("stores")
public Store getStore(Store store) {
    return store;
}
```

Comment: I still get null values for every store. I need to dynamically fill each form's input using `th:field`.