# Create form dynamically using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new in Spring MVC. I'm stuck for more than 24hrs trying to add a dynamic row using thymeleaf.  [I followed this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466032/thymeleaf-dynamically-create-forms-using-theach) and also the thymeleaf documentation [In this tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields) but i have not been able to make it work. Clicking **addRow** and **removeRow** doesn't work. Someone should please help me. Thanks

Here is my Controller code:

```
    @Controller
@SessionAttributes("qualification")
public class QualificationController {
    private final QualificationService qualificationService;
    private final StaffService staffService;
    private final CourseService courseService;

    @Autowired
    public QualificationController(QualificationService qualificationService,
                                   StaffQualificationService service,
                                   StaffService staffService, CourseService courseService) {
        this.qualificationService = qualificationService;
        this.staffService = staffService;
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }

    @GetMapping("/staff/{id}/qualification")
    public String initForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model) {

        Staff staff = staffService.findById(id);

        staff.addQualification(new StaffQualification());
        model.addAttribute("qualification", staff);

        model.addAttribute("qualifications", qualificationService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("courses", courseService.findAll());

        return "registration/qualification";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/staff/{id}/qualification/new", params = {"save"})
    public String addQualification(@ModelAttribute("qualification")
                                   @Valid Staff staff,
                                   BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes,
                                   SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration/qualification";
        }
        staffService.save(staff);
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Qualification successfully saved");
        status.setComplete();

        return "registration/qualification";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/staff/{id}/qualification/new", params = {"addRow"})
    public String addRow(final Staff staff, BindingResult result) {
        staff.getQuals().add(new StaffQualification());

        return "registration/qualification";
    }

    @PostMapping(params = "removeRow", path = {"/staff/{id}/qualification/new"})
    public String removeRow(final Staff staff, final BindingResult result,
                            final HttpServletRequest request) {

        final int rowId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("removeRow"));
        staff.removeQualification(staff.getQuals().remove(rowId));

        return "registration/qualification";
    }
}
```

My entities:

```
public class Staff extends NamedEntity {

@NotBlank(message = "First Name is blank")
private String firstName;

@NotBlank(message = "Last Name is blank")
private String lastName;

private String middleName;

@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10)
@NotBlank(message = "Please fill in your phone number")
private String phoneNumber;

private boolean married;

private String gender;
@Transient
private int age;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "staff", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<StaffQualification> quals = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "staff", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

```
public class StaffQualification extends BaseEntity {

private String qualification;
private String course;
private String school;

@NotNull(message = "Date obtained qualification must be in the past")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate qualDate;

@ManyToOne
private Staff staff;
```

}

Thymeleaf code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Staff form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="justify-content-start">
    <div th:include="fragments/bodyHeader.html"></div>
</div>
<div class="main body-content">
    <div class="container">
        
        <form th:object="${qualification}" th:action="@{/staff/{id}/qualification/new}" th:method="post">
            <div class="alert alert-info" th:if="${successMessage}" th:utext="${successMessage}"></div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="w-auto" th:text="#{qualification.staff}">Staff Qualifications</legend>
                <div>
                    <table id="items" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th th:scope="col">#</th>
                            <th th:scope="col">Title</th>
                            <th th:scope="col">Course</th>
                            <th th:scope="col">School</th>
                            <th th:scope="col" type="date">Date Obtained</th>
                            <th>
                                <button type="submit" name="addRow" th:text="#{qualification.row.add}">Add row</button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tbodyContainer">
                        <tr th:each="row, rowStat : *{quals}">
                            <td th:text="${rowStat.count}">1</td>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    <select th:field="*{quals[__${rowStat.index}__].qualification}">
                                        <option th:each="var : ${qualifications}"
                                                th:value="${var.id}"
                                                th:text="${var.name}">

                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    <select th:field="*{quals[__${rowStat.index}__].course}">
                                        <option th:each="let : ${courses}"
                                                th:value="${let.id}"
                                                th:text="${let.name}">

                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="text" th:field="*{quals[__${rowStat.index}__].school}"
                                           th:errorClass="fieldError"/>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="date" th:field="*{quals[__${rowStat.index}__].qualDate}"/>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" name="removeRow" th:value="${rowStat.index}"
                                        th:text="#{qualification.row.remove}">Remove row
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="save" style="margin-right: 50px" type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-actions row justify-content-center" style="padding-top:10px; padding-right: 200px">

                <a th:if="${qualification.id}" href="/staff/{id}/qualification"
                   th:href="@{/staff/{id}/qualification/(id=${qualification.id})}"
                   class="btn btn-primary">Next</a>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Account Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("account")
public class AccountController {
    private final PencomService pencomService;
    private final StaffService staffService;
    private final BankService bankService;

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(PencomService pencomService, StaffService staffService,
                             BankService bankService) {
        this.pencomService = pencomService;
        this.staffService = staffService;
        this.bankService = bankService;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }


    @GetMapping("/staff/{id}/account")
    public String initCreationForm(@PathVariable("id") Integer staffId, Model model) {

        Staff staff = staffService.findById(staffId);

        staff.setBankAccount(new BankAccount());
        staff.setPencomAccount(new PencomAccount());
        model.addAttribute("account", staff);

        model.addAttribute("listBanks", bankService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("listPensions", pencomService.findAll());

        return "registration/account";
    }

    @PostMapping("/staff/{id}/account/new")
    public String addAccount(@ModelAttribute("account") @Valid Staff staff,
                             BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes, SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration/account";
        } else {
            staffService.save(staff);
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "Accounts successfully saved");
            status.setComplete();

            return "/registration/account";
        }
    }

}
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.chairmo.cadre.controller.AccountController.initCreationForm(AccountController.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Can you show error message or explain the case?

Comment: I have added the error message and the related controller class