# How to change object field (status) by button (HTML) and stay in the same page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, crud

I would like to change the status field from current "ToDo" to "InProgress".

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="card-inner" th:if="${project.status.toString()=='ToDo'}" th:each="project: ${project}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="generateForm()">Action</button>

        <p th:text="${project.code}"></p>
        <p th:text="${project.name}"></p>
        <p th:text="${project.status.getDeclaringClass()}"></p>
        <a th:href="@{'projects/edit/' + ${project.id}}" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
        <a th:href="@{'projects/update/' + ${project.id}+'InProgress'}" class="btn btn-secondary">InProgress</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/update")
String update(@PathVariable Long id,@PathVariable String status) {
    Project project=projectService.getOne(id);
    project.setStatus(Status.valueOf(status)); // is an enum
    projectService.save(project);
    return "redirect:/projects";
}
```

Instead of going to `localhost:8080/projects` after clicking on `InProgress` it is going to `http://localhost:8080/projects/update/852InProgress`.

Comment: If you want to hit your `@PostMapping("/update")` controller, one option is to use a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) in your Thymleaf template and make that form use a `POST` method. Currently, your Thymeleaf is only generating a URL (not the URL you need to hit your controller) and that uses a `GET` (by default), not a `POST`.

Comment: [Thymeleaf dynamically create forms using th:each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54466032/12567365)